# Insert Menu Option into ApplicationIcon Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, titlebar

Windows applications have an icon in the top left of the titlebar, to the left of the application name? If you click it, it has options like `Restore`, `Minimize`, `Maximize`.. etc.

In many programs they have additional menu options there (beyond the default one's provided by Windows).  How can I implement this in C# Winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorials for "Customizing the System Menu in a Windows Forms Application":

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CustomWinFormSysMenu.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c9327

Snippet:

Import user32.dll to access the functions required to alter the system menu.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool InsertMenu (IntPtr hMenu, 
    Int32 wPosition, Int32 wFlags, Int32 wIDNewItem, 
    string lpNewItem);
```

Get the current system menu, and add items to it:

```
IntPtr sysMenuHandle = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
//It would be better to find the position at run time of the 'Close' item, but...

InsertMenu(sysMenuHandle, 5, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_SEPARATOR, 0, string.Empty);
InsertMenu(sysMenuHandle, 6, MF_BYPOSITION , IDM_CUSTOMITEM1, "Item 1");
InsertMenu(sysMenuHandle, 7, MF_BYPOSITION , IDM_CUSTOMITEM2, "Item 2");

public const Int32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
public const Int32 MF_SEPARATOR = 0x800;
public const Int32 MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;
public const Int32 MF_STRING = 0x0;
public const Int32 IDM_CUSTOMITEM1  = 1000;
public const Int32 IDM_CUSTOMITEM2 = 1001;
```

Capture the selection of the new custom items in order to assign methods to them:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    {
        switch(m.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            case IDM_CUSTOMITEM1 : 
                MessageBox.Show("Clicked 'Item 1'");
                return;
            case IDM_CUSTOMITEM1 :
                MessageBox.Show("Clicked 'item 2'");
                return;
            default:
                break;
        } 
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: could you provide a snippet of those instructions as well as your link?